# ASP.NET getting JSON object back from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to get a JSON object back through an ajax call but am unable to. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Here is my controller:

```
public class RandomController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a JSON representation of a Content corresponding to the content ID passed in.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public JsonResult GetStuff()
        {
            string x = "testing";
            return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and here is my ajax request:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#randombtn').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Random/GetStuff/',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and my button:

```
<input id="randombtn" type="button" value="Testing" />
```

Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: is ajax call going have you seen console??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put url this way using `@Url.Action()` helper to generate the right url from controller and action name to genrate right url:

```
$('#randombtn').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStuff","Random")',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

When you put **/Random/GetStuff** it will always look at this url for the action name. but using `@Url.Action()` will generate the proper url where ever you need url you can use this to get right url.

See [**MSDN Docs for Details**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#randombtn').click(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Random/GetStuff",function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

Try the above

Comment: that worked for some reason. Thanks. Any idea why .ajax doesn't work?

Comment: @SKLAK never harcode your url like this see my post, hope it helps, when you deploy  app at live what you will do you have to replace all places localhost with domain, so the right way is to use ``@Url.Action()`` helper